# Resource handler returned message: "invalid request provided: AWS::Logs::MetricFilter"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I am trying to set up a system in my log archive account that will send me an email notification when the RootTest IAM role is used to access my QA account.

To do this, In my log archive account, I am using CloudFormation to create a log group called CloudTrailLogs, and a CloudTrail trail that delivers CloudTrail log events to this log group. I also want to create a metric filter that searches the log events in the CloudTrailLogs log group for log events with the eventName field set to AssumeRole and the requestParameters.roleArn field set to arn:aws:iam::[QAAccountID]:role/RootTest. When the metric filter finds one or more matching log events, it will trigger a CloudWatch alarm. Finally, am creating an SNS topic and subscription that will send an email notification to a specified email address when the CloudWatch alarm is triggered.

Unfortunately, when I deploy the cloudformation template I have, it gives me the following error:

```
Resource handler returned message: "invalid request provided: AWS::Logs::MetricFilter"
```

The deployment errors out when trying to create the metric filter. Not sure where I am going wrong. Things with "[]" are redactions just in case. This is my template so far:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: CloudTrailLogs
  Trail:
    Type: AWS::CloudTrail::Trail
    Properties:
      S3BucketName: [Bucket Name]
      CloudWatchLogsLogGroupArn: !Ref LogGroup
      CloudWatchLogsRoleArn: !GetAtt CloudWatchLogsRole.Arn
  CloudWatchLogsRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
  MetricFilter:
    Type: AWS::Logs::MetricFilter
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Ref LogGroup
      FilterPattern: "{ $.eventName = 'AssumeRole' && $.requestParameters.roleArn = 'arn:aws:iam::[QAAccountID]:role/RootTest' }"
      MetricTransformations:
        - MetricValue: 1
          MetricNamespace: RootTestAccess
          MetricName: RootTestAccess
  Alarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: RootTestAccessAlarm
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      MetricName: RootTestAccess
      Namespace: RootTestAccess
      Period: 60
      Statistic: Sum
      Threshold: 1
      ActionsEnabled: true
      AlarmActions:
        - !Ref SNS
  SNS:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: RootTestAccessNotification
      TopicName: RootTestAccessNotification
  Subscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Protocol: email
      Endpoint: myemail@email.com
      TopicArn: !Ref SNS
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filter pattern is the problem. First you need to wrap the two terms separate in brackets (). You also need to use (") double quotes around the values, and not single quotes. So the FilterPattern key in the template should look like this:

```
FilterPattern: '{($.eventName = "AssumeRole") && ($.requestParameters.roleArn = "arn:aws:iam::012345678909:role/RootTest")}'
```